# Background Video Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, loops, video

I want to play a loop background video in my view. I wrote this code :

```
-(AVPlayerLayer*)playerLayer{

    if(!_playerLayer){

    // find movie file
     NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fond_login" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    _playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:movieURL]];
    _playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [_playerLayer.player play];
    return _playerLayer;
}
return nil; }

-(void)replayMovie:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"Finis");
[self.playerLayer.player play];}
```

And in my viewdidload, I have :

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(replayMovie:)
                                             name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

My problem is that the video don't play in loop. I see the video one time and it's finish. I don't know why ..

Thank's

**EDIT :**

I see another tutorial.

```
@import MediaPlayer;

@property (nonatomic, strong)  MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

My code in viewDidLoad :

```
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]   URLForResource:@"my_video" withExtension:@"format"];

self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;[self.view insertSubview:self.moviePlayer.view atIndex:0];
[self.moviePlayer play];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loopVideo) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayer];
```

And :

```
- (void)loopVideo {
[self.moviePlayer play]; }
```

It's work perfectly.

Comment: Do you ever see your replayMovie event fire?

Comment: No replayMovie wasn't called..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `replayMovie:` method you need to seek back to the beginning:

```
- (void)replayMovie:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [(AVPlayerItem *)notification.object seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

You're also going to want to set the `actionAtItemEnd` of the `AVPlayer` so it doesn't pause:

```
_playerLayer.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer !